# Customize dateCellRender in AntDesign

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is it possible to add class in Calendar component specifically in dateCellRender?
I'm creating this kind of module in AntDesign.

Here's an example

[Notice Calendar demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n29kr11zj)

I already created a state whenever I added an event in specific date.
And have a condition in the main calendar component

```
<Calendar
  className={
   state.isTaggedHoliday ? 'isTaggedHoliday' : 'isTaggedLeave'
  }
  dateCellRender={dateCellRender}
  monthCellRender={monthCellRender}
  onPanelChange={changeCalendarMode}
  onSelect={showLeaveListModal}
/>
```

But I'm not sure where to insert a class for that specific date marked in the calendar

Comment: I think you can add a react component in their but I'm not sure. Can you share some of your child component code.

Comment: The demo not working, please create a producible example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and by "add class" you mean styling it with css yes?

Comment: I already updated the link. or here it is https://codesandbox.io/s/n29kr11zj

Comment: @DennisVash Yes styling with css with particular class since I'm getting a specific date in calendar.

Comment: Where is the problem? You className 'events' works

Comment: That's the content. What I need is to add a class on each dateCells when checking the console, this is the class ```ant-fullcalendar-cell``` but there's no specific class or id to map what date has a content vs empty cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `className` but you need to target the right `CSS class`.

```
.ant-fullcalendar-fullscreen
  .ant-fullcalendar-month-panel-selected-cell
  .ant-fullcalendar-month,
.ant-fullcalendar-fullscreen
  .ant-fullcalendar-selected-day
  .ant-fullcalendar-date {
  background: palegreen;
}
```

> [Antd is a Design System](https://ant.design/docs/spec/introduce) so styling its component like this isn't recommended.

[image: Edit Q-58637965-AntdTableCell]

Comment: Yeah I get that part but just like  
```.ant-fullcalendar-fullscreen
  .ant-fullcalendar-selected-day
  .ant-fullcalendar-date {
  background: palegreen;
}``` I want to work the same with events content. I can add background-color as well, change the border-top etc